# Url Mask with url variable

Tags: php, html, redirect, iframe

I need to display a page without changing the url, I can do that, but I need the url values to be loaded as it is to display different links.

An example:

my url:https://faba.edu.br/diplomas/

Content I need to display:https://diplomadigital.techcert.com.br/validar

I can display the base content, but I also need to display it like this, a need to display on my url the follow link with variables link this.

my url: https://www.faba.edu.br/diplomas/validar/140.140.001ed8a3779c (i have error on this)

url a need to display, note this final of url can be changed: https://diplomadigital.techcert.com.br/validar/140.140.001ed8a3779c

But I can't, because it doesn't pass this value when loading the iframe.

How can I do this?

I use this code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Validador de Diplomas - Faculdade Bezerra de Araújo</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="0,*" border="0">
<frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize target="main">
<frame name="main" src="https://diplomadigital.techcert.com.br/validar/">
<noframes>
<body></body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: `frameset` and `frame` are not `iframe`.

Comment: How is this related to PHP?